# doremi: previous event triggering an error

Tags: debugging, with-simulated-input

In this example, the function `doremi` https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DoReMi seems to be encountering a problem due to the previous input.  Based upon that assumption, I have tried calling `discard-input` and also setting to `nil` the variables `last-command-event` and `last-input-event`.  **Q**:  **How can this particular issue be resolved**?

If at all possible, the example `my-func` should remain as-is when crafting a solution to this particular issue.  The ultimate goal will be to begin by calling `doremi-test-fn` with `down-mouse-2`, extract some goodies from that initial event, then call `my-func` using the initial event as an argument, then call `doremi` to select a string from `seq`, and finally use that selected string to craft a new custom list (in the form of a similuated mouse event) that will be passed as an argument to `my-func`.

[Due to the need for a minimal working example, `my-func` is called for the second (2nd) time when `doremi` exits.  However, I plan on calling `my-func` successively as `doremi` loops forwards/backwards through `seq`.  Hopefully, the suggested solution will still suffice.]

```lisp
(defun my-func (init-event)
  (interactive "e")
  (message "my-func:  %s" init-event))

(defun doremi-test-fn (init-event)
  (interactive "e")
  (let* ((init-win (selected-window))
         (seq '("a" "b" "c" "d"))
         (init-val "c")
         (start (event-start init-event))
         (window (posn-window start)) ;; nth 0
         (pos-or-area (posn-area start)) ;; nth 1
         (x-y (posn-x-y start)) ;; nth 2
         (timestamp (posn-timestamp start)) ;; nth 3
         (obj (posn-string start)) ;; nth 4
         (text-pos (posn-point start)) ;; nth 5
         (col-row (posn-actual-col-row start)) ;; nth 6
         (image (posn-image start)) ;; nth 7
         (obj-x-y (posn-object-x-y start)) ;; nth 8
         (obj-w-h (posn-object-width-height start)) ;; nth 9 position
         (the-event
           (list window
                 pos-or-area
                 x-y
                 timestamp
                 obj
                 text-pos
                 col-row
                 image
                 obj-x-y
                 obj-w-h))
         val)
    (my-func init-event)
    (discard-input)
    (setq last-input-event nil
          last-command-event nil)
    (doremi
      (lambda (newval)
        (prog1
          (setq val newval)
          (message "newval: %s" newval)))
      init-val 1 nil seq))
    ;;;
    ;;; Using the selected string from the `doremi' call above, craft a
    ;;; custom list to mimic/simulate the value returned by a mouse event.
    ;;;
    ;;; (my-func the-event--modified)
    )

(global-set-key [down-mouse-2] #'doremi-test-fn)
```

**BACKTRACE**

```
(error "‘doremi’, unexpected event: ‘(mouse-2 (#<window 52 on *TEST*> 20 (173 . 318) 32433130 nil 20 (14 . 2) nil (74 . 278) (11 . 20)))’ - report bug to drew.adams@oracle.com")
  signal(error ("‘doremi’, unexpected event: ‘(mouse-2 (#<window 52 on *TEST*> 20 (173 . 318) 32433130 nil 20 (14 . 2) nil (74 . 278) (11 . 20)))’ - report bug to drew.adams@oracle.com"))
  error("`doremi', unexpected event: `%S' - report bug to %s%s%s%s" (mouse-2 (#<window 52 on *TEST*> 20 (173 . 318) 32433130 nil 20 (14 . 2) nil (74 . 278) (11 . 20))) "drew.adams" "@" "oracle" ".com")
  (cond ((member evnt doremi-up-keys) (setq new-incr incr)) ((member evnt doremi-down-keys) (setq new-incr (if (atom incr) (- incr) (mapcar (function -) incr)))) ((member evnt doremi-boost-up-keys) (setq new-incr (if (atom incr) (* doremi-boost-scale-factor incr) (mapcar (function (lambda (in) (* doremi-boost-scale-factor in))) incr)))) ((member evnt doremi-boost-down-keys) (setq new-incr (if (atom incr) (* doremi-boost-scale-factor (- incr)) (mapcar (function (lambda (in) (* doremi-boost-scale-factor ...))) incr)))) ((and (consp evnt) (equal (quote mouse-wheel) (event-basic-type (car evnt)))) (setq new-incr (if (< 0 (nth 2 evnt)) incr (if (atom incr) (- incr) (mapcar (function -) incr)))) (if (event-modifiers evnt) (progn (setq new-incr (if (atom new-incr) (* doremi-boost-scale-factor new-incr) (mapcar (function ...) new-incr)))))) ((and (consp evnt) (member (event-basic-type (car evnt)) (list wheel-up wheel-down))) (let ((button (mwheel-event-button evnt))) (cond ((eq button mouse-wheel-down-event) (setq new-incr incr)) ((eq button mouse-wheel-up-event) (setq new-incr (if (atom incr) (- incr) (mapcar ... incr)))) (t (error "`doremi', bad mwheel-scroll binding - report bug to %s%s%s%s" "drew.adams" "@" "oracle" ".com")))) (if (if (> emacs-major-version 22) (doremi-intersection (event-modifiers evnt) (quote (shift control meta alt hyper super))) (event-modifiers evnt)) (progn (setq new-incr (if (atom new-incr) (* doremi-boost-scale-factor new-incr) (mapcar (function ...) new-incr)))))) (t (error "`doremi', unexpected event: `%S' - report bug to %s%s%s%s" evnt "drew.adams" "@" "oracle" ".com")))
  (while (progn (setq evnt (if (if (fboundp (quote display-graphic-p)) (display-graphic-p) window-system) (read-event prompt) (read-key prompt)) prompt nil) (or (member evnt keys) (and (consp evnt) (member (event-basic-type (car evnt)) (list (quote switch-frame) (quote mouse-wheel) (quote mouse-2) wheel-up wheel-down))))) (cond ((member evnt doremi-up-keys) (setq new-incr incr)) ((member evnt doremi-down-keys) (setq new-incr (if (atom incr) (- incr) (mapcar (function -) incr)))) ((member evnt doremi-boost-up-keys) (setq new-incr (if (atom incr) (* doremi-boost-scale-factor incr) (mapcar (function (lambda ... ...)) incr)))) ((member evnt doremi-boost-down-keys) (setq new-incr (if (atom incr) (* doremi-boost-scale-factor (- incr)) (mapcar (function (lambda ... ...)) incr)))) ((and (consp evnt) (equal (quote mouse-wheel) (event-basic-type (car evnt)))) (setq new-incr (if (< 0 (nth 2 evnt)) incr (if (atom incr) (- incr) (mapcar (function -) incr)))) (if (event-modifiers evnt) (progn (setq new-incr (if (atom new-incr) (* doremi-boost-scale-factor new-incr) (mapcar ... new-incr)))))) ((and (consp evnt) (member (event-basic-type (car evnt)) (list wheel-up wheel-down))) (let ((button (mwheel-event-button evnt))) (cond ((eq button mouse-wheel-down-event) (setq new-incr incr)) ((eq button mouse-wheel-up-event) (setq new-incr (if ... ... ...))) (t (error "`doremi', bad mwheel-scroll binding - report bug to %s%s%s%s" "drew.adams" "@" "oracle" ".com")))) (if (if (> emacs-major-version 22) (doremi-intersection (event-modifiers evnt) (quote (shift control meta alt hyper super))) (event-modifiers evnt)) (progn (setq new-incr (if (atom new-incr) (* doremi-boost-scale-factor new-incr) (mapcar ... new-incr)))))) (t (error "`doremi', unexpected event: `%S' - report bug to %s%s%s%s" evnt "drew.adams" "@" "oracle" ".com"))) (if (and (consp evnt) (memq (event-basic-type (car evnt)) (quote (mouse-2 switch-frame)))) (message save-prompt) (condition-case failure (setq init-val (cond ((ring-p enum) (if (and allow-new-p ...) (progn ...)) (if (< ... 2) (progn ...)) (let* (... ...) (if ... ... ...))) ((functionp growth-fn) (if (atom new-incr) (if ... ... ...) (if ... ... ...))) (growth-fn (doremi-set-new-value setter-fn new-incr)) ((and (numberp new-incr) (numberp init-val)) (doremi-set-new-value setter-fn (+ init-val new-incr))) (t (error "`doremi' - Bad argument.  INIT-VAL: %S, INCR: %S" init-val new-incr)))) (error (error "%s" (error-message-string failure))))))
  (let ((prompt (format "Use %s, %s, or mouse wheel to adjust value" (single-key-description (car doremi-up-keys)) (single-key-description (car doremi-down-keys)))) (keys (append doremi-up-keys doremi-down-keys doremi-boost-up-keys doremi-boost-down-keys)) (echo-keystrokes 0) (wheel-down mouse-wheel-up-event) (wheel-up mouse-wheel-down-event) evnt save-prompt) (if enum nil (setq prompt (concat prompt " (modifier key: faster)"))) (setq prompt (format (concat prompt ".  Value now: %s") init-val) save-prompt prompt) (while (progn (setq evnt (if (if (fboundp (quote display-graphic-p)) (display-graphic-p) window-system) (read-event prompt) (read-key prompt)) prompt nil) (or (member evnt keys) (and (consp evnt) (member (event-basic-type (car evnt)) (list (quote switch-frame) (quote mouse-wheel) (quote mouse-2) wheel-up wheel-down))))) (cond ((member evnt doremi-up-keys) (setq new-incr incr)) ((member evnt doremi-down-keys) (setq new-incr (if (atom incr) (- incr) (mapcar (function -) incr)))) ((member evnt doremi-boost-up-keys) (setq new-incr (if (atom incr) (* doremi-boost-scale-factor incr) (mapcar (function ...) incr)))) ((member evnt doremi-boost-down-keys) (setq new-incr (if (atom incr) (* doremi-boost-scale-factor (- incr)) (mapcar (function ...) incr)))) ((and (consp evnt) (equal (quote mouse-wheel) (event-basic-type (car evnt)))) (setq new-incr (if (< 0 (nth 2 evnt)) incr (if (atom incr) (- incr) (mapcar ... incr)))) (if (event-modifiers evnt) (progn (setq new-incr (if ... ... ...))))) ((and (consp evnt) (member (event-basic-type (car evnt)) (list wheel-up wheel-down))) (let ((button (mwheel-event-button evnt))) (cond ((eq button mouse-wheel-down-event) (setq new-incr incr)) ((eq button mouse-wheel-up-event) (setq new-incr ...)) (t (error "`doremi', bad mwheel-scroll binding - report bug to %s%s%s%s" "drew.adams" "@" "oracle" ".com")))) (if (if (> emacs-major-version 22) (doremi-intersection (event-modifiers evnt) (quote ...)) (event-modifiers evnt)) (progn (setq new-incr (if ... ... ...))))) (t (error "`doremi', unexpected event: `%S' - report bug to %s%s%s%s" evnt "drew.adams" "@" "oracle" ".com"))) (if (and (consp evnt) (memq (event-basic-type (car evnt)) (quote (mouse-2 switch-frame)))) (message save-prompt) (condition-case failure (setq init-val (cond ((ring-p enum) (if ... ...) (if ... ...) (let* ... ...)) ((functionp growth-fn) (if ... ... ...)) (growth-fn (doremi-set-new-value setter-fn new-incr)) ((and ... ...) (doremi-set-new-value setter-fn ...)) (t (error "`doremi' - Bad argument.  INIT-VAL: %S, INCR: %S" init-val new-incr)))) (error (error "%s" (error-message-string failure)))))) (message nil) (setq unread-command-events (cons evnt unread-command-events)))
  (let ((new-incr incr)) (if (and enum (sequencep enum)) (progn (setq enum (ring-convert-sequence-to-ring enum)))) (let ((prompt (format "Use %s, %s, or mouse wheel to adjust value" (single-key-description (car doremi-up-keys)) (single-key-description (car doremi-down-keys)))) (keys (append doremi-up-keys doremi-down-keys doremi-boost-up-keys doremi-boost-down-keys)) (echo-keystrokes 0) (wheel-down mouse-wheel-up-event) (wheel-up mouse-wheel-down-event) evnt save-prompt) (if enum nil (setq prompt (concat prompt " (modifier key: faster)"))) (setq prompt (format (concat prompt ".  Value now: %s") init-val) save-prompt prompt) (while (progn (setq evnt (if (if (fboundp ...) (display-graphic-p) window-system) (read-event prompt) (read-key prompt)) prompt nil) (or (member evnt keys) (and (consp evnt) (member (event-basic-type ...) (list ... ... ... wheel-up wheel-down))))) (cond ((member evnt doremi-up-keys) (setq new-incr incr)) ((member evnt doremi-down-keys) (setq new-incr (if (atom incr) (- incr) (mapcar ... incr)))) ((member evnt doremi-boost-up-keys) (setq new-incr (if (atom incr) (* doremi-boost-scale-factor incr) (mapcar ... incr)))) ((member evnt doremi-boost-down-keys) (setq new-incr (if (atom incr) (* doremi-boost-scale-factor ...) (mapcar ... incr)))) ((and (consp evnt) (equal (quote mouse-wheel) (event-basic-type ...))) (setq new-incr (if (< 0 ...) incr (if ... ... ...))) (if (event-modifiers evnt) (progn (setq new-incr ...)))) ((and (consp evnt) (member (event-basic-type ...) (list wheel-up wheel-down))) (let ((button ...)) (cond (... ...) (... ...) (t ...))) (if (if (> emacs-major-version 22) (doremi-intersection ... ...) (event-modifiers evnt)) (progn (setq new-incr ...)))) (t (error "`doremi', unexpected event: `%S' - report bug to %s%s%s%s" evnt "drew.adams" "@" "oracle" ".com"))) (if (and (consp evnt) (memq (event-basic-type (car evnt)) (quote (mouse-2 switch-frame)))) (message save-prompt) (condition-case failure (setq init-val (cond (... ... ... ...) (... ...) (growth-fn ...) (... ...) (t ...))) (error (error "%s" (error-message-string failure)))))) (message nil) (setq unread-command-events (cons evnt unread-command-events))))
  doremi((lambda (newval) (prog1 (setq val newval) (message "newval: %s" newval))) "c" 1 nil ("a" "b" "c" "d"))
  (let* ((init-win (selected-window)) (seq (quote ("a" "b" "c" "d"))) (init-val "c") (start (event-start init-event)) (window (posn-window start)) (pos-or-area (posn-area start)) (x-y (posn-x-y start)) (timestamp (posn-timestamp start)) (obj (posn-string start)) (text-pos (posn-point start)) (col-row (posn-actual-col-row start)) (image (posn-image start)) (obj-x-y (posn-object-x-y start)) (obj-w-h (posn-object-width-height start)) (the-event (list window pos-or-area x-y timestamp obj text-pos col-row image obj-x-y obj-w-h)) val) (my-func init-event) (discard-input) (setq last-input-event nil last-input-event nil) (doremi (function (lambda (newval) (prog1 (setq val newval) (message "newval: %s" newval)))) init-val 1 nil seq))
  doremi-test-fn((down-mouse-2 (#<window 52 on *TEST*> 20 (173 . 318) 32432910 nil 20 (14 . 2) nil (74 . 278) (11 . 20))))
  funcall-interactively(doremi-test-fn (down-mouse-2 (#<window 52 on *TEST*> 20 (173 . 318) 32432910 nil 20 (14 . 2) nil (74 . 278) (11 . 20))))
  call-interactively(doremi-test-fn nil nil)
  command-execute(doremi-test-fn)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now at least, try commenting out the last `cond' clause (with` t`) in the code of function` doremi` - the one that raises that error:

```lisp
(t (error "`doremi', unexpected event: `%S' etcetera" evnt))
```

That should enable it to work for you.

The right fix is likely to move the test and true branch of the `if` that follows that `cond` into the `cond`, just before that last "unexpected event" clause.

That seems to do the right thing.  IOW, move that into the `cond', and keep the false branch of that` if`after the`cond` doing it unconditionally there.

Thanks for the report. I uploaded the fix - please download the latest here: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/doremi.el

Comment: Based upon the answer, everything appears to be working now with the test example -- thank you.